# Is it possible to send a request to the Facebook Graph API from client side without exposing our access token to the public?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token, app-secret

My question is related to, but not exactly, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633234/get-public-page-statuses-using-facebook-graph-api-without-access-token).

I am currently working on a business directory Web site (similar to Yelp), in which businesses have their own pages. Let's call this app `DIRECTORY_APP`.

Businesses might want to have their latest Facebook status update shown on their pages hosted on our directory. Let's pretend we have a business named `BIZ_1`. The assumption is that those pages are public pages.

Apparently the Facebook Graph API can be used for this purpose. So I can send a request to Facebook to retrieve the latest status updates for `BIZ_1`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/BIZ_1_PROFILE_ID/posts?
        access_token=DIRECTORY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
        &callback=callbackName
```

However, if I use this from the client side, our Web site's access token will be exposed to the public, so this is not a reasonable solution.

Now in the [aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633234/get-public-page-statuses-using-facebook-graph-api-without-access-token), Anatoly mentions that we can retrieve the access token by sending this request first:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
        &grant_type=client_credentials
```

However if someone inspects the Network log, this will also expose our Web site's access token (is this correct or is this a different type of access token?). This solution also exposes our web site's app secret (is this safe?).

So to summarize, what's a safe way in which I can retrieve the latest status update of a Web page from client-side without asking the browsing user to first log in to Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after some Googling. In short, the answer is no.

And here's an excerpt from [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/):

## Security Best Practices

### App Secret and App Access Token

The App Secret is used in some of the Login flows to generate access tokens and the Secret itself is intended to secure usage of your App to only those that are trusted. The secret can be used to easily create an App Access Token which can make API requests on behalf of any user of the app, which makes it extremely important that an App Secret is not compromised.

Therefore the App Secret or an App Access token should never be included in any code that could be accessed by anyone other than a developer of the app. This applies to all methods of code that are not secured like client-side code (such as HTML or Javascript) or native apps (such as iOS, Android or Windows desktop apps) that could be decompiled.

We recommend that App Access Tokens should only be used directly from your app's servers in order to provide the best security. For native apps, we suggest that the app communicates with your own server and the server then makes the API requests to Facebook using the App Access Token. For this reason, if your 'App Type' under Advanced Settings in the App Dashboard is set to Native/Desktop we assume that your native app contains the App Secret or an App Access Token in the binary, and we do not allow calls signed with an App Access Token to proceed. The API will behave as though no access token was provided.

If your App Secret is compromised, you should reset it immediately in the Basic Settings of your App Dashboard.

Comment: This information is not actual now. Please check provided by you link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview - it doesn't contains such text any more.

Comment: It still contains it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/ The way to prevent compromise is by always transmitting it over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

> I can retrieve the latest status update of a Web page from client-side without asking the browsing user to first log in to Facebook

You cant do that without login.

And I guess access token is **not** exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the smart trick here is to use a social plugin. The [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) will do what you want, without any issues. But, it's not greatly customizable. Even so, it's possible to get it looking nice on a page!

It also skips any login issues you mentioned.