# Fetch Facebook public page content in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, koala-gem

I need to fetch content(posts) of a facebook public page in my rails application.
And we dont provide FB login functionality. How this can be achieved from server side, any approach for implementing this with Koala.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an access token for that. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633234/get-public-page-statuses-using-facebook-graph-api-without-access-token).