# Using Facebook Graph API without User Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

### What I want to achieve

I want to display posts of a public facebook page on my website. For that reason it does not make sense to use a user access token, since it requires a login.

### Possible Solution I found

I know you can use the [App Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens). There was a related question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633234/get-public-page-statuses-using-facebook-graph-api-without-access-token). I tested this using the Graph API Explorer.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/google/statuses`

returns: `(#100) Requires user session`

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/google/posts`

returns: a valid result, but a totally different result than the same request with a User Access Token (less posts). same request for nike delivers a better result.

### Questions

- Why does the same request deliver two diferent results?
- Can you only grab certain posts with the app token?
- Under which conditions can you get the full timeline without user access token?

Comment: Posts might f.e. be targeted to specific user groups (based on location, language, age, …) – and those you will only get using a user access token for a user that satisfies the targeting criteria. Using your app token, you will only get posts that “everyone” can see.

Comment: seems reasonable. for me this wasn't understandable in the docs. I posted messages on a wall, which I think should be visible for everyone, yet I still do not retrieve them.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the docs. There's a fundamental difference between `posts` and `statuses`, and the permission requirements are also well documented:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#readperms
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/status
  *

Quotes:

> - An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
> - A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
> - A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.

Comment: I understand that i cannot retrieve statuses. But why do I get less results on posts with a valid app token?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/google/posts delivers two different results when using it with user token and app token. can you only grab certain posts with the app token?

Comment: I made posts on a wall, which should be visible to everyone, yet I still do not recieve them. I gave you an upvote, but it still does not explain, how I can solve my problem.