# get facebook news feed from different sites in android app

Tags: android, facebook

I want to show(and only show) the news feed of some different facebook-sites.
In my case it is all about icehockey: i want to show the newsfeed of some differnet sites like: 
https://www.facebook.com/penguins/?fref=ts

https://www.facebook.com/groups/305981342861167/?fref=ts

- i am not the owner of the sites!
- i only want to show the newsfeed (no comments, likes..)
- authentication should NOT be necessary in my app

Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: Use an app access token on your server and fetch them using the API

Comment: is it possible to do this without server(dirctly in my app)?

Comment: You need an access token. So in that case the user needs to logs in in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the below posts; you would get answer for your question!

1. [Embed activity feed of a public Facebook page without forcing user to login/allow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660728/embed-activity-feed-of-a-public-facebook-page-without-forcing-user-to-login-allo?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Get public page statuses using Facebook Graph API without Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633234/get-public-page-statuses-using-facebook-graph-api-without-access-token?rq=1)
3. [Can you get a public Facebook page's feed using Graph API without asking a user to allow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373645/can-you-get-a-public-facebook-pages-feed-using-graph-api-without-asking-a-user?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api