# Extract public posts from Facebook page without API/APP key/token/secret

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook, cheerio, app-secret

Just to clarify in advance, I don't have a Facebook account and I have no intent to create one. Also, what I'm trying to achieve is perfectly legal in my country and the USA.

Instead of using the Facebook API to get the latest timeline posts of a Facebook page, I want to send a get request directly to the page URL (e.g. [this page](https://www.facebook.com/pg/officialstackoverflow/posts/)) and extract the posts from the HTML source code.
(I'd like to get the text and the creation time of the post.)

When I run this in the web console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('userContent')
```

I get a list of elements containing the text of the latest posts.

But I'd like to extract that information from a nodejs script. I could probably do it quite easily using a headless browser like `puppeteer` or the like, but that would create a ton of unnecessary overhead. I'd really like to a simple approach like downloading the HTML code, passing it to cheerio and use cheeriio's jQuery-like API to extract the posts.

Here is my attempt of trying exactly that:

```
// npm i request cheerio request-promise-native
const rp = require('request-promise-native'); // requires installation of `request`
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

rp.get('https://www.facebook.com/pg/officialstackoverflow/posts/').then( postsHtml => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(postsHtml);

    const timeLinePostEls = $('.userContent');
    console.log(timeLinePostEls.html()); // should NOT be null
    const newestPostEl = timeLinePostEls.get(0);
    console.log(newestPostEl.html()); // should NOT be null
    const newestPostText = newestPostEl.text();
    console.log(newestPostText);
    //const newestPostTime = newestPostEl.parent(??).child('.livetimestamp').title;
    //console.log(newestPostTime);
}).catch(console.error);
```

unfortunately `$('.userContent')` does not work. However, I was able to verify that the data I'm looking for is embedded somewhere in that HTML code.

But I couldn't really come up with a with a good regex approach or the like to extract that data.

Depending on the post content the number of HTML tags within the post varies heavily.

Here is a simple example of a post containing one link:

```
<div class="_5pbx userContent _3576" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;&#125;"><p>We&#039;re proud to be named one of Built In NYC&#039;s Best Places to Work in 2019, ranking in the top 10 for Best Midsize Places to Work and top 3 (!) for Best Perks and Benefits. See what it took to make the list and check out our profile to see some of our job openings. <a href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F2H3Kbr2&amp;h=AT29h2HyDsEk0rHRWqJA-Fa4M1qi3nJT1NBi95othaR3qeFuFAMNiVS2Dgtv5KR5m0xqjw6kfwZdhZt0_D3UQT1Oel2UhxRql-KwkA1xqWvrql4u1jDhzrkGVT_XxoUd8_w8_fzLZzzhz23a8yPCK6IPfWKB76_CEFjG3b78y4dFJvY9Z08AYlR01dmi5_FvWVEVytkN-123u6alYE8pqL6Jb6dtIQUTWGXYJPaNMrtxkCUZniEVXEcILkwHGSuHqCTAarboyMP55F1vhYO3OAiVMkvjbN274fVq92YvbK3bi90bU9T-5ADWHDUJ-CwcofSBTW47chstQeY0n_UluD_rBIPLsfXVSnCtpRkR2kXi9zzHLnNeIYeNssv3i7UKS_f5Z2pnVT6xe3zJbNpB68doH1Z__I9nsTCNIyFyKx2VxabecoL03DIawbRrzBoxLAwzNPLACBjTkpEQhdVn4_wdAIjXRL4cLQDcZkLEoG_sspBgRePH23TFbNufQOBly-FNtLHnkUDO2Ca-FYvAGXpcu6J4B1aH3XFPB803lsz-GRdACyOFOgXDXJfwr4WtWzUHxfiOPULWiI43yI5L4aU6wYRhPjxua3RuRZ8oj9fXa1w4Jrht94Ue2wfKtz8" target="_blank" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;-U&quot;&#125;" rel="noopener nofollow" data-lynx-mode="async">http://*******/2H3Kbr2</a></p></div>
```

Formatted in a more readable form it looks somewhat like this:

```
<div class="_5pbx userContent _3576" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;&#125;">
    <p>
        We&#039;re proud to be named one of Built In NYC&#039;s Best Places to Work in 
        2019, ranking in the top 10 for Best Midsize Places to Work and top 3 (!) for 
        Best Perks and Benefits. See what it took to make the list and check out our 
        profile to see some of our job openings.
        <a href="VERY_LONG_URL.........." target="_blank" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;-U&quot;&#125;" rel="noopener nofollow" data-lynx-mode="async">SHORT_LINK.....</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

This regex [seems](https://regex101.com/r/EMIrnx/1/) to work okay, but I don't think it is very reliable:

```
/<div class="[^"]+ userContent [^"]+" data-ft="[^"]+">(.+?)<\/div>/g
```

If for example the post contained another div-element then it wouldn't work properly. In addition to that I have no way of knowing the time/date the post was created using this approach?

Any ideas how I could relatively reliably extract the most recent 2-3 posts including the creation date/time?

Comment: If you cast a close vote, please explain why so I can adjust my question.

Comment: Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, no matter if it is legal in your country. not sure why there is a close vote though, your question is quite detailed. itś just not allowed, that is pretty much the only valid answer ;)

Comment: It is allowed in my country. There have been many court cases. Oracle for example has lost a court case (they didn't want people to download Java from their website using a script).

Comment: you may want to talk to a lawyer about that, but you will definitely not get help here with something that is clearly not allowed on facebook. same rules for everyone on facebook, no matter which country you are.

Comment: in other words: their platform, their rules. as a honest developer, you should respect that, no matter if there are court cases allowing it in your country.

Comment: No, their EULA cannot override the law. Every browser, search engine crawler and even tons of browser extensions are accessing Facebook this way.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I finally figured it out. I hope this will be useful to others. This function will extract the 20 latest posts, including the creation time:

```
// npm i request cheerio request-promise-native
const rp = require('request-promise-native'); // requires installation of `request`
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

function GetFbPosts(pageUrl) {
    const requestOptions = {
        url: pageUrl,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0'
        }
    };
    return rp.get(requestOptions).then( postsHtml => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(postsHtml);
        const timeLinePostEls = $('.userContent').map((i,el)=>$(el)).get();
        const posts = timeLinePostEls.map(post=>{
            return {
                message: post.html(),
                created_at: post.parents('.userContentWrapper').find('.timestampContent').html()
            }
        });
        return posts;
    });
}
GetFbPosts('https://www.facebook.com/pg/officialstackoverflow/posts/').then(posts=>{
    // Log all posts
    for (const post of posts) {
        console.log(post.created_at, post.message);
    }
});
```

Since Facebook messages can have complicated formatting the message is not plain text, but HTML. But you could remove the formatting and just get the text by replacing `message: post.html()` with `message: post.text()`.

**Edit:**
If you want to get more than the latest 20 posts, it is more complicated. The first 20 posts are served statically on the initial html page. All following posts are retrieved via ajax in chunks of 8 posts.
It can be achieved like that:

```
// make sure your node.js version supports async/await (v10 and above should be fine)
// npm i request cheerio request-promise-native
const rp = require('request-promise-native'); // requires installation of `request`
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

class FbScrape {
    constructor(options={}) {
        this.headers = options.headers || {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0' // you may have to update this at some point
        };
    }

    async getPosts(pageUrl, limit=20) {
        const staticPostsHtml = await rp.get({ url: pageUrl, headers: this.headers });
        if (limit <= 20) {
            return this._parsePostsHtml(staticPostsHtml);
        } else {
            let staticPosts = this._parsePostsHtml(staticPostsHtml);
            const nextResultsUrl = this._getNextPageAjaxUrl(staticPostsHtml);
            const ajaxPosts = await this._getAjaxPosts(nextResultsUrl, limit-20);
            return staticPosts.concat(ajaxPosts);
        }
    }

    _parsePostsHtml(postsHtml) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(postsHtml);
        const timeLinePostEls = $('.userContent').map((i,el)=>$(el)).get();
        const posts = timeLinePostEls.map(post => {
            return {
                message: post.html(),
                created_at: post.parents('.userContentWrapper').find('.timestampContent').html()
            }
        });
        return posts;
    }

    async _getAjaxPosts(resultsUrl, limit=8, posts=[]) {
        const responseBody = await rp.get({ url: resultsUrl, headers: this.headers });
        const extractedJson = JSON.parse(responseBody.substr(9));
        const postsHtml = extractedJson.domops[0][3].__html;
        const newPosts = this._parsePostsHtml(postsHtml);
        const allPosts = posts.concat(newPosts);
        const nextResultsUrl = this._getNextPageAjaxUrl(postsHtml);
        if (allPosts.length+1 >= limit)
            return allPosts;
        else
            return await this._getAjaxPosts(nextResultsUrl, limit, allPosts);
    }

    _getNextPageAjaxUrl(html) {
        return 'https://www.facebook.com' + /"(\/pages_reaction_units\/more[^"]+)"/g.exec(html)[1].replace(/&amp;/g, '&') + '&__a=1';
    }
}

const fbScrape = new FbScrape();
const minimum = 28; // minimum number of posts to request (gets rounded up to 20, 28, 36, 44, 52, 60, 68 etc... because of page sizes (page1=20; all_following_pages=8)
fbScrape.getPosts('https://www.facebook.com/pg/officialstackoverflow/posts/', minimum).then(posts => { // get at least the 28 latest posts
    // Log all posts
    for (const post of posts) {
        console.log(post.created_at, post.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why does it extract only 20 posts? Is it possible to have more?

Comment: This solution doesn't work in US or in Germany. The access gets blocked. Try it on reqbin.com

Comment: I just tested it and it definitely still works! reqbin is not the right tool to test this. Just use nodejs.

Comment: @Forivin does it extract posted images?

Comment: @Forivin It's not extracting the posted images. How should I tackle that?